# why we use .car file in WAS?

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad-7.5

I am new to Websphere Applciation server, i want to know why we using .car in **Websphere Application Server** ? 
1) Is it used to Restore the Database?
2) Is it contains SQL data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .car is a "configuration archive". It is one way to clone or backup/restore an application server profile (which is roughly an instance).  It is more middleware configuration than anything you'd think of a database / SQL data.  Backup/resotre of databases would not be managed through an application server.